# It is possible to format bold text on mini magick (Imagemagick)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, markdown, minimagick

I have a diploma generator on Ruby on Rails which draw some text variables over an image template and now I need to highlight certain words in one statement

For example (notice bold over expertise):

> Has met the certification requirements
> and is recognized as **expertise** in **cohort_name**
> fulfilling **hours** of classes and **online_hours** hours of study

I know Imagemagick permits drawing text with certain fonts, but i'm looking something similar, but only applying over certain words.

My template text:

> Ha cumplido con los requerimientos de la certificación
> y se reconoce como :expertise en :cohort_name
> cumpliendo :hours horas de clases y :online_hours horas de estudio

My code:

```
 def formatted_text(text)
   formatted_text = text
   formatted_text = formatted_text.gsub(/:cohort_name/, cohort_name.to_s)
   formatted_text = formatted_text.gsub(/:hours/, hours.to_s)
   formatted_text = formatted_text.gsub(/:online_hours/, online_hours.to_s)
   formatted_text = formatted_text.gsub(/:expertise/, expertise.to_s)
   formatted_text
end     

 image_cert = MiniMagick::Image.open(cert.url)
 image_cert.combine_options do |c|
   if certification_type.footer_text
     c.gravity "West"
     c.draw "text 120,80 '#{formatted_footer}'"
   end
 end
```

Desired result
[image: sample cert image]

Comment: Use Pango:. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#pango

Comment: Sure, seems like the right tool, but i can't find enough documentation on how to use with mini magick